# Spacing values to calculate a gradient using numpy.gradient in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I would like to calculate a gradient for my "speed" column in my dataframe, it would corresponds to **dx**:

[image]

I would like to calculate the gradient so that my **dy** would be the "Timestamp" column...but... I would like to space the formula by a number of rows:

- for example if I space from four rows the gradiant at the 5th index would be (88-27)/(1.0-0.2)
- I don't know how to specify that because when I do `np.gradient(df["speed"], df["Timestamp"])` it uses a unitary spacing

Here is the code for my dataframe `df=pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6],'speed':[27,27,27,86,86,86,74,74,74,88,88,88,62,62,62,62]})`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply slicing on the dataframes to achieve the spacing and then apply gradient.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6],'speed':[27,27,27,86,86,86,74,74,74,88,88,88,62,62,62,62]})

import numpy as np
g1 = np.gradient(df["speed"], df["Timestamp"]) 

spacing = 4

g2 = np.gradient(df["speed"][::spacing], df["Timestamp"][::spacing])
```

Out:

```
[ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  2.95000000e+02  2.95000000e+02
  0.00000000e+00 -6.00000000e+01 -6.00000000e+01  0.00000000e+00
  7.00000000e+01  7.00000000e+01  5.68434189e-14 -1.30000000e+02
 -1.30000000e+02 -1.13686838e-13  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
[147.5   58.75 -30.   -30.  ]
```

You can do something like this as your requirement is different:

```
def gradient(y, x, spacing=1):
    y_c = np.pad(y, (spacing-1, spacing-1), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))
    x_c = np.pad(x, (spacing-1, spacing-1), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))
    dydx = []
    #print(y)
    #print(y_c)
    for i in range(1, y.shape[0]):
        dy = y_c[i+spacing-1] - y_c[i-1]
        dx = x_c[i+spacing-1] - x_c[i-1]
        dydx.append(dy/dx)

    return np.array(dydx)
```

N.B: this result won't match numpy gradient for spacing = 1 as numpy uses default 2 step size for dy/dx calculation.

Comment: I'm sorry but this only give me 4 values because the spacing actually is a jump in your case ... but I want to consider each value

Comment: How do you want to handle the edge cases?

Comment: order 2 while it's possible and order 1 for the edge

Comment: I don't want to use an iteration method but pre-compiled functions so that the treatment is much faster...